Would the reaction force from the base increase when people are pumping the hydraulic jacks?
I have a hydraulic cylinder on a support base that is going to lift Mass A. When lifting, the user have to exert a force on the jack handle that is pointing downward, right? So when the pumping action occurs, the force felt by the base is equal to the sum of the weight of the hydraulic cylinder, the weight of Mass A, and the force exerted on the handle by the user, right?

the handle does not move in an up-down manner ... the force applied to the jack is not the same as the force applied to the handle

Your assessment is correct. If values of the forces involved are important, consider that the force on the handle is quite small.

Image from linked site.
The lever action (class two lever) starts with the mechanical advantage of the effort being well outside the load and fulcrum points. The user forces on the load (lever) is then magnified hydraulically by the piston on the lever, transferred to the piston carrying the main load. The last load value is going to be the highest, while the others are miniscule in comparison.
